# what are these regex expressions meaning?

Tags: php, regex

1. `preg_match( '/<title>(.*)<\/title>/',.....)`
2. `preg_match("/src=[\"']?([^\"']?.*(png|jpg|gif))[\"']?/i",....)`

Comment: Looks like they would extract information from a HTML page. The title and the addresses of images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first is to extract the contents from a HTML `title` tag.

The second is to extract images' `src` attributes from a HTML document, but is very imperfect (It won't catch references to image resources that end in `.jpeg` or have no extension at all).

**Regular expressions are [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348) for parsing HTML!** One should [use a HTML parser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662). They are far from fireproof.

Comment: @Pekka Yes, always tell'em [to not do that](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). +1

Comment: Note that the first regex will fail if the line (or, in multi-line mode, the _entire document_) has multiple `<title>` elements. That may be unlikely for this specific case but in general produces very bad results.

Comment: why the edit? `The regexes will probably both do a half-way decent job - if part of an existing project, you can probably leave them be. But they are far from fireproof, and if you're building stuff from scratch, don't use this approach.` Most people will continue to use bad code but the should be encouraged to fix it instead.

Comment: Also I thinknthe second regex is terrible too for the same reason. It's very lazy about validating what can and can't be in a string and may grab too much unless I'm badly mistaken.

Comment: @beggs I'd say it depends on the situation. If it's a newbie finding his way through production code, it won't be their first priority. In general however, you're right, edited that out. @Chris good points!

Comment: i want to know what are these signals(/ (.*)  \) meaning.

Comment: @runeveryday they are patterns and delimiters. `(.*)<\/title>` means "grab everything up to the next occurrence of `</title>` and return it as part of the result. The `/` is used as a delimiter around the expression. There's some more info here http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

Comment: thank you,i know, but to the second line code. why there is no / delimiter after ]?/i

Comment: @runeveryday `i` is a flag that comes after the delimiter, specifying case insensitive search (in order to also catch `JPG`, `GIF` ....)

Answer (score 0):

1) Matches anything between `<title>` and `</title>` a la an HTML page's title, so run against `<title>foo</title>` results in the match being `foo`.

2) Matches any string following `src=` that ends in `png`, `jpg` or `gif`.  Used to extract the URL of images in HTML code.

Per @Pekka's answer: don't do this in real world code.